# putting input text inside the image and make it responsive(css)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put the input textfield inside my image. I already put my code inside my flexbox however the flexbox is working and responsive but when i do try to put the textfield inside the image. Its not working.The problem is even i try to make the input position to relative its still not display inside the image and not responsive. Can someone help me

```css
    body {
        background-image: url(images/loading_bg.png);
        background-position: center center;
  
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
        background-attachment: fixed;
  
        background-size: cover;
  
        background-color:#464646;
    }
    .box {
        width:80%;
        min-height:80vh;
        margin:auto;
        border:1px solid;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center; /* not really needed with auto margin on img*/
        margin-top: -80px;
     }
     .box input {
        position:relative;
        width: 20%;
        height: auto; /* maintain aspect ratio*/
        margin: auto; /*optional centering of image*/
        margin-left: 50%;
     }
     .box img {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 80%;
        min-width:100px;
        max-width: 450px; /*actual image width*/
        height: auto; /* maintain aspect ratio*/
        margin: auto; /*optional centering of image*/
     }

     /* For mobile devices */
     @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        body {
        /* The file size of this background image is 93% smaller
        * to improve page load speed on mobile internet connections */
            background-image: url(images/loading_bg.png);
        }
     }
```

```html
    <!-- Tutorial URL: http://sixrevisions.com/css/responsive-background-image/ 
    -->

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Responsive Full Background Image</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="author" content="Six Revisions">
        <meta name="description" content="How to use the CSS background-size 
        property to make an image fully span the entire viewport.">
        <link rel="icon" href="http://sixrevisions.com/favicon.ico" 
        type="image/x-icon" />
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
        family=Kotta+One|Cantarell:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"> 
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="presentational-only/presentational- 
        only.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive-full-background-image.css">
  
        <script 
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> 
        </script>
        <script src="presentational-only/presentational-only.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header class="container">
        <section class="content">
            <div class="box">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x250" width="350" 
                height="250" alt="missing image">
             </div>
             <p><a class="button" id="load-more-content" href="#top">Load some 
             content</a></p>
         </section>
    </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for??.. i have put image and input in 1 div .outer.
Made it position relative and and the input absolute and adjusted it accordingly.
thanks

```css
body {
        background-image: url(images/loading_bg.png);
        background-position: center center;
  
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
        background-attachment: fixed;
  
        background-size: cover;
  
        background-color:#464646;
    }
    .box {
        width:80%;
        min-height:80vh;
        margin:auto;
        border:1px solid;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center; /* not really needed with auto margin on img*/
          /* margin-top: -80px; */
     }
     .box input {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    /* margin-left: 50%; */
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translatey(-50%);
     }
     .box img {
            position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 450px;
    height: auto;
    /* margin: auto; */
}
     
     
     .outer{
     position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    margin: auto;}

     /* For mobile devices */
     @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        body {
        /* The file size of this background image is 93% smaller
        * to improve page load speed on mobile internet connections */
            background-image: url(images/loading_bg.png);
        }
     }
```

```html
<!-- Tutorial URL: http://sixrevisions.com/css/responsive-background-image/ 
    -->

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Responsive Full Background Image</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="author" content="Six Revisions">
        <meta name="description" content="How to use the CSS background-size 
        property to make an image fully span the entire viewport.">
        <link rel="icon" href="http://sixrevisions.com/favicon.ico" 
        type="image/x-icon" />
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
        family=Kotta+One|Cantarell:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"> 
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="presentational-only/presentational- 
        only.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive-full-background-image.css">
  
        <script 
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> 
        </script>
        <script src="presentational-only/presentational-only.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header class="container">
        <section class="content">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="outer"> 
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x250" width="350" 
                height="250" alt="missing image">
                </div>
             </div>
             <p><a class="button" id="load-more-content" href="#top">Load some 
             content</a></p>
         </section>
    </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```